# SQL Rule/Constraint for Sharing

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table with consisting of columns:

```
device_id
account_id
is_owner
```

with device_id and account id as conglomerate primary key

How can I create an SQL Rule/Constraint such that when the is_owner is true with the conglomerate primary key it will not allow another combination of

```
device_id = (specific device id)
account_id = (any account id) 
is_owner = true
```

since the owner of the device should be only one,

and that:

```
device_id  = (specific device id)
account_id = (any account id)   
is_owner = false
```

can be 'many' since a device can be shared by the owner account to another account?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use partial index:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX idx_name 
   ON table_name(device_id, account_id)       --or only (device_id) if needed
WHERE is_owner = true;
```

**[DBFiddle Demo](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=60ea15816ff4e422d1550187f1838fd4)**

Example:

```
CREATE TABLE t(device_id INT NOT NULL, account_id INT NOT NULL, is_owner BOOL);
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX idx_name ON t(device_id, account_id)
WHERE is_owner = true;
INSERT INTO t(device_id, account_id, is_owner)
VALUES( 1,1, false),(1,1,false);

SELECT * FROM t;

INSERT INTO t(device_id, account_id, is_owner)
VALUES( 1,2, true),(1,2,true);
--ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "idx_name"
--DETAIL:  Key (device_id, account_id)=(1, 2) already exists.
```